# Building an EXE with Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c++, exe

I'm unclear on how to do this. All I can find on the internet is that you build and then the exe will automatically appear in the project file, but that is not the case for me. I just tried setting up an extremely basic C++ project with one main.cpp of this:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hey ho!" << std::endl;
}
```

It runs all nice and well in Visual Studio, but there is no EXE in the project. Am I doing something wrong? Also, for the record, this is the output I get when I build:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: ConsoleApplication1, Configuration: Release Win32 ------
1>  main.cpp
1>  Generating code
1>  Finished generating code
1>  ConsoleApplication1.vcxproj -> c:\users\oysi\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Release\ConsoleApplication1.exe
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: Where are you looking for the file? This is where you should be looking for it, VS says it all: `c:\users\oysi\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Release\ConsoleApplication1.exe`.

Comment: HAHA, I was looking inside Project/Project/Release and not Project/Release... Damn me. Well, despite my antivirus hating me, it runs. =D Thanks, I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

As Visual tells you, you should look for `.EXE` file in this directory:

`c:\users\<username>\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Release\ConsoleApplication1.exe`

Answer (score 1):

Try `F5`, it will build and run your project. If you put a breakpoint at the closing bracket (`}`) of `main`, you'll even see your output in the console.

The .exe won't be added to the project, but it will be created in the output directory. The output you copied here actually tells you, where you can find the .exe:

```
c:\users\oysi\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\ConsoleApplication1\Release\ConsoleApplication1.exe
```